# Error message: unable to resolve the name obj.key

Tags: matlab, class, oop

I'm creating a class that launches a frequency attack on a message `m`. I have started with two functions, one constructor and one display. For some reason I keep getting the error message

> Unable to resolve the name `obj.key`.

What does this error message mean and how do I solve it?

```
classdef Attack
    properties
       key
    end

    methods
        function obj = Attack(m)
            % ....
        end

        function display(m)
           out = decryption(obj.key,m);
           disp(['Using the key:', obj.key, char(13), 'Your (partially) decrypted message is:', out]);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: you are not supposed to erase your answer xD There might be other people having the same issue and are happy that someone has asked it before

Comment: Please don't delete your post after it has been answered. This is considered vandalism. You contributed a question to the site, it now belongs to the site.

Answer (score 1):

`obj` is not visible in your method `display`. You need to hand it over explicitly

```
classdef Attack
    % tries to decrypt a permutation-cipher encoded message

    properties
       key
       % ....
    end

    methods
        function obj = Attack(m)
            % ....
        end

        function display(obj,m) % hand over the object!
           disp(obj.key);
        end
    end
end
```

Have a look at this little [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/create-a-simple-class.html).